# How to append two dataframes in pandas and print it out to an excel file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, append, pandas-groupby

I want to work on my excel file tb.xlsx and group the data by a column named 'Hybrid type' and then store the new dataframe back in another excel file.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("D:\\tb.xlsx")
group=df.groupby("Hybrid type")
print(group)
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for Hybridtype,frame in group:
    df2=pd.DataFrame(frame)
    df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
df1.to_excel("Montu.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

When I run this, it's giving output:

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000272FD41B108>
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Electricity generation price per unit, Primary load demand, Hybrid type, Biomass type, Location, Country, System Type, Ref.]
Index: []
```

I think the append()command is not working properly here as my df1 database is empty.
Can someone please help me with my code?

Comment: please share sample input of the excel and what sample output is.

Comment: thanks but the problem was with the append() statement only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. In contrast to native python, DataFrame.append() is not an in-place function. It's easy to forget ;)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("D:\\tb.xlsx")
group=df.groupby("Hybrid type")
print(group)
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for Hybridtype,frame in group:
    df2=pd.DataFrame(frame)
    df1 = df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
print(df1)
df1.to_excel("Montu.xlsx",sheet_name="Sheet1")
```

Answer (score -1):

A few days back I also ran into a similar issue. Since I don't know what is the content of your xlsx I used a sample file to reproduce this issue.

Issue:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("/home/aakash/Downloads/file_example_XLS_100.xls")
group=df.groupby("Country")
print(group)
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for Hybridtype,frame in group:
    df2=pd.DataFrame(frame)
    df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True)
print(df1)

<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fe9b48eba90>
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, First Name, Last Name, Gender, Country, Age, Date, Id]
Index: []
```

Solution:
As per the official documentation,"Dataframe.append" function append rows of other to the end of the caller, returning a new object.
so the modified code should be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel("/home/aakash/Downloads/file_example_XLS_100.xls")
group=df.groupby("Country")
print(group)
df1=pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for Hybridtype,frame in group:
    df2=pd.DataFrame(frame)
    df1=df1.append(df2,ignore_index=True) ## Modified code
print(df1)

<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x7fe9b4380f60>
      0 First Name   Last Name  Gender        Country Age        Date    Id
0     3     Philip        Gent    Male         France  36  21/05/2015  2587
1    12   Franklyn      Unknow    Male         France  38  15/10/2017  2579
2    16   Shavonne         Pia  Female         France  24  21/05/2015  1546
3    17     Shavon      Benito  Female         France  39  15/10/2017  3579
```